# Remove non-numeric elements from a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of elements that have sparse non-numeric values which I would like to remove. I would like to use a function that searches for non-numeric elements in my list and then remove them.

Since I am generating multiple lists randomly, I cannot use a simple basic function

```
mylist[[-c("element.I.dont.want")]]
```

The function `mylist[[is.numeric(mylist)]]` does not work.
Here is an example of a list I have:

```
mybadlist <- list(c(1,2), c(3,4), c("error here","error here"), c(2,2))
```

And here is the list I want:

```
mygoodlist <- list(c(1,2), c(3,4), c(2,2))

mygoodlist
```

Comment: `mybadlist[sapply(mybadlist, is.numeric)]`

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @IceCreamToucan It would be great if you had posted it as an answer (and the OP accepted it) so this appears as a solved question in search.